# Good way to insert html atributes in blade template based on conditions in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade, bootstrap-4

I know that there are other question addressing this issue but they mostly cover adding a value to an attribute based on a variable.  I want to include several attributes and their values based on a condition.

My first attempt, as you can see below, besides not working is not very readable:

```
<input
type="text" 
{{ $errors->has('bedrooms') ? "data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' 
title='please, enter a value between 1 and 9.'" : "" }}

/>
```

Produces the html:

```
<input type="text"
data-toggle=&quot;tooltip&quot; data-placement=&quot;right&quot; 
title=&quot;please, enter a value between 1 and 9.&quot />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your blade syntax to `{!! !!}`

```
<input type="text" 
  {!! $errors->has('bedrooms') ? "data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title='please, enter a value between 1 and 9.'" : "" !!}
/>
```

By default, Blade escape Html - [See the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data)